# How to Scale a Canvas to the Width of the Space It's In

Tags: canvas, fabricjs

I have a canvas and I'd like it to remain a square but scale to the width of the div that it's inside to make it responsive. So for example, I'd like to have this canvas scale to the div's max-width but retain its shape/scale:

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("c");
canvas.setHeight(350);
canvas.setWidth(350);
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.test {
max-width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.22/fabric.min.js"></script>

<div id="test">
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: set width of canvas as parent div width.

Comment: When I try to do that in the CSS, or the JS, and even the `canvas` tag in the HTML, it becomes the right width but the height doesn't scale appropriately. Would you mind elaborating how you'd have the canvas scale proportionately?

Comment: You want to give parent div container `#test`  width to canvas right?

Comment: @Durga Yes, and it scale

Comment: check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/durga598/cL9j2k0w/)

Comment: With the fiddle, I see the width change but the height doesn't proportionally change—what do I need to do to get it to retain its shape but resize? What I mean is, for example, if the canvas is square it should remain a square but be the width of the DIV; the height is the same as the width in this example because it is square. Thank you. If you post as an answer I can accept it as solved!

Comment: Set width value to height of canvas, let say if div width is 500px,you want to set width and height of canvas = 500, right?

Comment: @Durga exactly but say for example’s sake that the doc is responsive; the canvas should size with it but remain a square

Comment: Whatever width you will get, use that as height